# git clone from Azure DevOps failing

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops

I can clone from a git repository hosted in Azure DevOps on an Windows Azure VM, but I can't clone on my local Windows machine anymore (I used to be able to). So, I can rule out permissions issues on the repository.

I can clone git repositories from an internally hosted TFS.

git version: 2.21.0.windows.1

```
C:\Users\someuser\dev>git clone https://somOorg@dev.azure.com/someOrg/someProject/_git/someRepository
Cloning into 'someRepository'...
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier someRepository does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://someOrg@dev.azure.com/someOrg/someProject/_git/someRepository/' not found
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you verify that the repo exists in Azure DevOps? Like going to the repo through the UI and validating the correct clone URL? Are you also able to verify that you have the correct access level (license) in AzDO as well as contributor permissions to the repo? Could there be any security change from your internal network that may block off access to the Internet for the repo?

Comment: It’s actually a colleague having this issue. I was able to clone the repository. So, the repo does exist. I know permissions can’t be the issue because they can clone on an Azure VM, but not to a machine inside our firewall. I can clone on my machine inside the firewall, so it can’t be a general network setting. I think it has to be something specific to their computer.

Comment: Can you clone the repo using your credentials on his machine?

Comment: We’ll try 1. their computer with different credentials and 2. their credentials with a different computer. What we’re seeing with their computer though is that it never prompts for credentials.